# undefined behavior или нет?

Tags: c

В одном из тестов в один из проектов от Mail.ru group встретил следующий код на языке С:

```
int b = 11;
int a = ++b / 2 / 2 * 3 / 9 - b++ + 1;
```

Есть ли в этом выражении UB?

Если я правильно понимаю, то между двумя точками следования будет `(++b / 2 / 2 * 3 / 9 - b++ + 1)`, где переменная `b` изменяется дважды. А такой случай не предусмотрен стандартом и результат зависит от реализации.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Undefined.

В подтверждение этого утверждения могу привести диагностику:

`warning: operation on ‘b’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]`

от gcc (и g++) -Wall

Comment: Классическое UB, описанное у K&R. "в С в основном не указывается порядок вычисления операндов в операциях. (Исключения составляют `&&`, `||`, `?` и `,`)"